# matplotlib max_open_warning data overload

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I got this code where I have to use 2000 plots and stack them on each other.
I do it like this:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 8)) 
N=45
ind=np.arange(N)
for bar in range(0,2000,):
    y=[dic[value][bar] for value in dic]
    plt.bar(ind,y,bottom=lista[0])
    plt.close(fig)
```

And then I get a warning :

> RuntimeWarning: More than 20 figures have been opened. Figures created
>   through the pyplot interface (matplotlib.pyplot.figure) are retained
>   until explicitly closed and may consume too much memory. (To control
>   this warning, see the rcParam figure.max_num_figures).
>   max_open_warning, RuntimeWarning)

The script runs forever. Is there a way to solve this ?

Comment: Where do you define `fig`?

Comment: @StefanS I added that now. Thought it was irrelevant

Comment: As suspected, `plt.close(fig)` doesn't do a lot, because you only close the `fig`-figure in the first loop iteration. Since you no longer have an active figure from the second iteration onwards, `plt.bar` creates a new one, which you never close. Although I do not understand why you think you have 2000 plots and where you "stack" them. Do you want N bars in one figure, but each bar consists of 2000 stacked bars? That would be one plot, so define an axis and plot with `ax.bar` within the loop.

Comment: And don't close the figure inside the loop, of course.

Comment: Yes I want N bars in one figure, but each bar consists of 2000 stacked bars

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: You do not provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), what kind of answer do you expect? But I see that you seemingly use a dictionary, so [this pandas solution might or might not guide you](https://pstblog.com/2016/10/04/stacked-charts)

Comment: that will do i think. Thanks